# How to get value after mutation in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, getter-setter, vuex, vuex-modules

I have simple `Vuex` module for global date object:

```
import moment from 'moment';

const state = {
    date: moment()
}

// getters
const getters = {
    date: state => state.date,
    daysInMonth: state => state.date.daysInMonth()
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
    subtractOneDay(state) {
        state.date.subtract(1, 'days');
    }
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    mutations
}
```

One of my child components:

```
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex';

export default {
    computed: Object.assign(mapGetters(['date', 'daysInMonth']), {}),
    methods: {
        subtractOneDay() {
            this.$store.commit('subtractOneDay');

            console.log(this.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), this.date.daysInMonth(), this.daysInMonth)
        }
    },
    created() {
        console.log('blocks created')
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('blocks mounted')
    }
}
```

Basically I need to get days of month (29, 29, 30 or 31) when `date` is changed.

The problem is that computed property `daysInMonth` doesn't change...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment's `subtract` method *mutates* the referenced moment object. That is an issue for Vue, because it means the *reference* to `state.date` hasn't changed and the computed properties will not re-compute their value.

You can work around this using moment's `clone` method to return a new moment in the `subtractOneDay` method.

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state:{
    date: moment()
  },
  getters:{
    date: state => state.date,
    daysInMonth: state => state.date.daysInMonth()
  },
  mutations: {
    subtractOneDay(state) {
        state.date = state.date.clone().subtract(1, 'days');
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  computed: Object.assign(Vuex.mapGetters(['date', 'daysInMonth']), {}),
  methods:{
    subtractOneDay(){
      this.$store.commit('subtractOneDay');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{date}}
  <hr>
  {{daysInMonth}}
  <hr>
  <button @click="subtractOneDay">Subtract 1 Day</button>
</div>
```

Comment: oh, i thought that `commit` does the mutation

Comment: `commit` runs the `subtractOneDay` mutation, yes. But in `subtractOneDay`, the date object itself is changed, it doesn't turn into a new date. Because of that, Vue doesn't know anything changed. The solution is to set `date` to a new moment object.